# How to properly declare a child route for the angular router?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I've the following routing:

```
//Root routes
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthenticatedLayoutComponent, //All childs pages will have headers
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'documents', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'documents', loadChildren: () => import('./documents/documents.module').then(m => m.DocumentsModule) },
      { path: 'settings', loadChildren: () => import('./settings/settings.module').then(m => m.SettingsModule) },
      { path: 'accounts', loadChildren: () => import('./account/account.module').then(m => m.AccountModule) },
    ],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    //The goal of separating auth and account is to have the pages to becomes authentified in the Auth module, with a totally different layout
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule),
    canActivate: [UnauthGuard],
  },
];
```

and then, for the child "AccountModule", I've the following routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'profile', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

My `AuthenticatedLayoutComponent` has basically just a header/footer and a router-outlet:

```
<div id="container" class="flex flex-column w-screen">
  <header class="flex-grow-0 z-1">
    <app-header></app-header>
  </header>
  <main class="flex-grow-1 z-0">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>
  <footer class="flex-grow-0 z-1">
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```

- If I try to access to `http://localhost:4200/accounts/profile` everything works
- But a strange thing is that if I'm trying to access to `http://localhost:4200/profile` I'm also redirected to my ProfileComponent, without my header/footer.

Why is this considered a valid path and how do I prevent it?

Comment: I'm confused as to why `/profile` redurects you to `/accounts/profile` because it's not a child route of your main routing module. Can you reproduce this?

Comment: It may help to catch wildcard `**` routes in your routing configuration to avoid these problems entirely.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally imported `AccountModule` or `AccountRoutingModule` in your application root module?

Comment: The only thing that I see a little odd here is that the empty route with the redirectTo in AccountModule goes after the `/profile` route that is used in the redirection. Angular match the routes in order. Dont know for sure if a redirect to a route that is behind can cause this problem.

Comment: Not sure how you set up the routing in the lazy loaded module, but in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#inside-the-feature-module), the routing definition is extracted into its own module. Could you add more information here?

Comment: @JSONDerulo You're on to something. `AccountModule` is actually imported inside the AppModule, because it does contains the `AuthGuard`.  Is there a way to make it work or do I have to find a way to split those AuthGuard and AuthService somewhere else?

Comment: @JSONDerulo Yes, in my case, `AccountsModule` has its own routing module, your link is my exact setup.

Answer (score 2):

Like figured out in the comments, the problem is that the application root module imports `AccountModule` because it contains something that the application root module needs. In that moment, the route definition of the `AccountModule` is loaded, which exposes the `/profile` route.

One way to fix it, is to resolve the dependency between the root module and the `AccountModule`, and stop importing it. Then the module with its route definition is only loaded via lazy loading, making the `/profile` route unavailable. But possibly this will be a lot of effort.

Another quicker way to fix it, is to remove lazy loading from the `/accounts` route and define its sub-routes directly in your root routing module:

```
//Root routes
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthenticatedLayoutComponent, //All childs pages will have headers
    children: [
      // ...
      {
        path: 'accounts',
        children: [
          { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'profile', pathMatch: 'full' },
        ]
      },
    ],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  // ...
];
```

Comment: The thing is the dependency is here because the `AuthGuard` is in this module, so is the AccountState and the AccountService. There will be dependencies between all those classes and the other components of other modules, I'm not sure how to avoid this. I don't really care about lazy loading for this module, but I do care about having the routing in a sub-module, do you see another way of doing it without lazy loading?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but unfortunately, since we will have quite a lot of rules, I'm looking for a way to keep the routes of one module inside of this module. Is there a way to NOT lazy-load, but still have the routes in a dedicated accounts RoutingModule ?

Comment: I tried to move my guards(that are required in the AppRoutingModule) in another module(which needs to import the AccountModule), but same result. only option to split would be to split totally the AccountModule in two, one with the pages, and the other with the state + services + guards. I would like to avoid this if possible

Answer (score 0):

Strongly inspired by @JSONDerulo answer:

Since I cannot use lazy loading but I still would like to have my rules enclosed in my accounts module:

1. I now declare the module in my AppModule
2. I export my account routes and use them as childs in my AppRoutingModule
3. I removed the import of the AccountRoutingModule of my AccountModule

**AppRoutingModule:**

```
import { routes as accountsRoutes } from './account/account-routing.module';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthenticatedLayoutComponent, //All childs pages will have headers
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'documents', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'documents', loadChildren: () => import('./documents/documents.module').then(m => m.DocumentsModule) },
      { path: 'settings', loadChildren: () => import('./settings/settings.module').then(m => m.SettingsModule) },
      { path: 'accounts', children: accountsRoutes },
    ],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    //The goal of separating auth and account is to have the pages to becomes authentified in the Auth module, with a totally different layout
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule),
    canActivate: [UnauthGuard],
  },
];
```

**AccountRoutingModule**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'profile', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```